# comparing the string value with indexof with whole string

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, comparison, indexof

I have a string that can get any possible value like below (Please note, 2 of the values could be of same like message1, message4 below, however, remember it could be with same or different casing but I want to ignore casing and compare in from a list I am getting this).

```
string Message = "No need of validation";
string Message = "No need of validation for certain members only"
string Message = "Validation for this member - No need of validation"
string Message = "no need of validation";

Message.IndexOf("No need of validation", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
```

Now my code above would return true/false for 2, 3rd scenarios?

I expect true only for 1,4 and false for 2,3. Please confirm me. If this is not correct ,pls help me with modifying my code

Comment: Are you asking if you're correct about how string.IndexOf works, or are you asking how to compare strings for equality ignoring case?

Answer (score 0):

If you run as is, all 4 will be true.

```
        string Message = "No need of validation";
        Console.WriteLine("1 : {0}", Message.IndexOf("No need of validation", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        Message = "No need of validation for certain members only";
        Console.WriteLine("2 : {0}", Message.IndexOf("No need of validation", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        Message = "Validation for this member - No need of validation";
        Console.WriteLine("3 : {0}", Message.IndexOf("No need of validation", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        Message = "no need of validation";
        Console.WriteLine("4 : {0}", Message.IndexOf("No need of validation", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

This is because ignoring case the 'compare' string exists in each of your message strings somewhere, so the index will always be 0 or higher.

If you want to compare whether the strings are equal to each other irregardless of case then you should use string Compare instead:

```
        Message = "No need of validation";
        Console.WriteLine("1 : {0}", string.Compare(Message,"No need of validation", true));
        Message = "No need of validation for certain members only";
        Console.WriteLine("2 : {0}", string.Compare(Message, "No need of validation", true));
        Message = "Validation for this member - No need of validation";
        Console.WriteLine("3 : {0}", string.Compare(Message, "No need of validation", true));
        Message = "no need of validation";
        Console.WriteLine("4 : {0}", string.Compare(Message, "No need of validation", true));
```

Which will give you the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the results correctly, you could use the Ye old `string.Compare`, its been around since .Net 1.1

[Compare(String, String, CultureInfo, CompareOptions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Compare_System_String_System_String_System_Globalization_CultureInfo_System_Globalization_CompareOptions_)

> Compares two specified String objects using the specified rules, and
>   returns an integer that indicates their relative position in the sort
>   order.

**Returns**

> Int32 A 32-bit signed integer that indicates the lexical relationship
>   between strA and strB, as shown in the following table
>
> Value Condition
>
> - Less than zero  strA precedes strB in the sort order.
> - Zero    strA occurs in the same position as strB in the sort order.
> - Greater than zero   strA follows strB in the sort order.

**Example**

```
string Message1 = "No need of validation";
string Message2 = "No need of validation for certain members only";
string Message3 = "Validation for this member - No need of validation";
string Message4 = "no need of validation";
Console.WriteLine(string.Compare("No need of validation", Message1, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
Console.WriteLine(string.Compare("No need of validation", Message2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
Console.WriteLine(string.Compare("No need of validation", Message3, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
Console.WriteLine(string.Compare("No need of validation", Message4, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

**Output**

```
0
-1
-1
0
```

Comment: thank you. I am working in .net 4.5 and I need to separate the order of words at least by 1 in each case so that I get distinct comparison for different scenarios and only that particular message matching will execute condition

Comment: @Learner do you mind adding that information and anything else you seem relevant to your question